# Symfony 3 Sonata Admin Bundle Form Mapper

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

My symfony app has a "course" entity with ('id', 'course_title' and 'prerequisite'). Using the SonataAdminBundle to insert the data into the database as follows:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{

    $formMapper->add('id', 'text');
    $formMapper->add('course_name', 'text');
    $formMapper->add('prerequisite', 'entity', [
      'class' => 'AppBundle:Course',
      'choice_label' => 'id',
      'placeholder' => 'Choose a prerequisite',
    ]);
}
```

The prerequisite 'id' is supposed to be inserted in the database but it ends up with prerequisite 'course_name' inserted instead!

Comment: `course_name` is inserting to db or just to form?

Comment: couse_name is inserted into the form and the database

Comment: did you read this: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/form_types.html ? you need to provide another field type for sonata.